# express-session excessive MySQL SELECT/UPDATE session calls

Tags: mysql, node.js, express-session

I'm using [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) with [sequelize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize) and [connect-session-sequelize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-session-sequelize) within my Node.js App. By default express-session logs all SQL calls, which highlighted the issue I am trying to resolve. A call to a view template via res.render('index') initiates both a `SELECT` and `UPDATE` call as expected (below):

```
Executing (default): SELECT `sid`, `expires`, `data` FROM `session` AS `session` WHERE `session`.`sid` = 'T84YX7hvKWmihWPMzT0Cg_97Wao7kCF5';
Executing (default): UPDATE `session` SET `expires`=? WHERE `sid` = ?
```

However, adding linked header elements (`style`/`script` tags) or `img` tags within the template results in an additional call to both the `SELECT` and `UPDATE` query for every linked element. As a result, adding more content will result in an exponential number of database calls.

How can I prevent `style`,`script` and `img` calls from initiating the call within express?

app.js

```
const config    = require('./config');      
const http      = require('http');
const express   = require('express');
const session   = require('express-session');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    config.dbDatabase,
    config.dbUser,
    config.dbPassword,
    {
        host    : config.dbHost,
        dialect : config.dbDialect,
        define  : {
            timestamps  : false,
            underscored : true
        }
    }
);

const app = express();

const sequelizeStore = require('connect-session-sequelize')(session.Store);
const sessionStore = new sequelizeStore({
    db: database.sequelize,
    modelKey: 'session'
});

app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', './views');

app.use(express.static('./public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index'); // pug 
}

const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(config.port, () => {
    console.log(`App listening on port: ${config.port}`);
});
```

index.pug

```
doctype html
html
    head
        meta(charset='utf8')
        title example
        link(rel='stylesheet' href='/css/example.css')
        script(src='/js/lib/angular/angular.min.js')
        script(src='/js/lib/angular/angular-resource.min.js')
        script(src='/js/example.min.js')
    body
        H1 Example Template
        img(src= "/img/sample.jpg" alt="Sample image")
```

Comment: can you provide some code snippet?

Comment: Hi @AkashPatel, I've updated the question with code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused when `app.use(express.static('./public'));` is used after `app.use(session({...});`. Hope this helps anyone else encountering the same issue.